# Correct way to check if a variable is HUGE_VAL in C

Tags: c, infinity

I have a variable in C which can contain the values HUGE_VAL or -HUGE_VAL. I can see there exists a function called isfinite() complying with C99, which is the standard I use. But according to the man page it detects between finite values and infinite or NaN, but it does not talk about HUGE_VAL. What is the "correct" way to check for a HUGE_VAL value? Could be simply `variable==HUGE_VAL` or is there any specific function?

Comment: Yes you can do a direct comparison to `HUGE_VAL` (and its variants).

Answer (score 2):

`HUGE_VAL` is an ordinary floating-point value; you can test whether the value of `variable` is `HUGE_VAL` with `variable == HUGE_VAL`, and you can test whether it is `-HUGE_VAL` with `variable == -HUGE_VAL`.